# How to bridge to remote gits

Tags: git, cordova, bitbucket

I am new to Git and trying to bridge between BitBucket and PhoneGapBuild. I think the way to do this is checkout from BitBucket then push to PhoneGapBuild. The problem is I have not been able to get that to work.

What is a good way to create a one-way push from one git to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can *directly* push between BitBucket and PhoneGapBuild private Git repo.

I would still recommend:

- cloning your BitBucket Git repo locally
- add a remote address to your PhoneGapBuild Git repo (following the [Git Hosting doc](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/git-hosting)):
  `git remote add PhoneGapBuild`
- `git push PhoneGapBuild  master`

Answer (score 1):

I think is possible to directly link PhoneGap Build with a Bitbucket private repo using [basic http authentication](http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/using-private-bitbucket-repositories-with-phonegap-build):

```
https://my_bitbucket_user:my_bitbucket_password@bitbucket.org/my_bitbucket_user/test-private-repo.git
```

Try adding this url in your "private code" tabs in PhoneGap Build app settings.